# Is there a way to set the default sort statement for a table in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: oracle

I have a log table like this:

```
fill_logs(
  log_id        number,
  text          varchar2(1000),
  executed_on   date,
  ...
)
```

It saves a log of some operations. And when I query this table I want this query to be sorted in descending order of the `executed_on` column by default. Sounds stupid, but I don't want to write `order by` clause every time.

Comment: The **only** (really: the only) way to guarantee a specific sort order is to use `order by`. There is no alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So create a view `SELECT * FROM FILL_LOGS ORDER BY EXECUTED_ON` and use that view instead of the table.